# Explain Why does this C code give output False?

Tags: c, relational-operators

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=4,b=15,c=29;
    if(c>b>a)
    {
        printf("True");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code in my dev C++ compiler, it gives me the following output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1FRj.png)

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
c>b>a
```

is same as

```
((c>b) > a)
```

The output of a relational operator, like `>` is either `0` or `1`, and the type is `int`.

Either of those values, in this case, is less than the value of `a`, which is `4`. So in your case (b=15,c=29), it becomes

```
(1 > a)
```

which is falsy.

If you want to *chain* the condition check, you should write

```
((c>b) && (b>a))
```